How to find the period of a trigonometric function out of its graphical representation
I don't know how to find period on this graph, from what I know it should be the distance between full cycle points. On this graph we don't see the other point so I'm confused.
Hereby my graph:


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

from the information given you can work out half the period (horizontal axis)

From the description (find period of a graph) it's as good as impossible to find the period, but there is a catch here: your function seems to be a simple trigonometric one ($a \sin(bx)+c$), and those functions have a very important property:

You have a maximum, then a minimum, then again a maximum and then again a minimum, and so on, and every maximum's X-coordinate is precisely in the middle of the X-coordinates of two subsequent minima, and vice versa.

So, as one maximum has X-coordinate $\frac{3 \pi}{4}$ and the next minimum has X-coordinate $2 \pi$, it's quite easy to calculate the X-coordinate of the previous minimum or of the next maximum, and from there you can calculate the period.
Why is that middle-thing so important? Well, imagine that this would be the graph of your function:

You wouldn't have a way to calculate the period.

$\sin x = \cos (x - \frac{\pi}{2})$, so every sine is a cosine and vice versta :-)

From the picture you can assume that this is a scaled and translated sine wave. As you noted, the period is then the difference in $x$-values of successive maxima which is the same as the difference in $x$-values of successive minima.
But sine waves also have another property: The difference of $x$-values between one maximum and the next minimum is half of the period. Given that information, can you calculate the period of the given function?
